# CMake Generators not all there?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to find the Visual Studio Generators on my platform installation of `cmake`. If it's important, I'm running on Linux, but am a bit confused why the Visual Studio generators would be system specific.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html

Running `cmake --help` results in:

```
The following generators are available on this platform:
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  KDevelop3                    = Generates KDevelop 3 project files.
  KDevelop3 - Unix Makefiles   = Generates KDevelop 3 project files.
```

Comment: @ixSci Sure, however solution files are used more than just for MSVS, `xbuild` by Mono generates solution files just fine on Linux for .NET builds. I fail to see the importance of the operating system in regards to the build system, they seem separate.

Comment: .net can be built on Linux just fine, Mono is the thing for it. MSVS is not that easy and AFAIK it requires Wine. So when you have a proper env setup (wine) you can use Win cmake to generate whatever you need. Why env setup? Because during generation process CMake tests compiler by building some code and you obviously can't do it on Linux w/o proper setup.

Comment: @ixSci oh that makes sense, I'll give that a shot. Would you like to put that into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon generating the files required to build the app based on a CMake script, CMake has to determine a few bits of information about the requested generator (which is either provided explicitly by `-G` or some default one). In order to gather that information CMake compiles some C and C++ code (you can look at the CMake output where it spits some info about checking for C compiler, then C++ compiler) with a compiler associated with the given generator. So given we would like to generate MSVS project files, we need to have a working MSVC compiler installed on our system and that compiler should be able to build the code CMake wants to build.

That's why CMake can't provide MSVS generator on *pure* Linux. So in order to make CMake do it on Linux you have to run `CMake.exe` on Linux with MSVC installed, which, to my knowledge, is possible with the help of Wine.